# Update Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 failed

Tags: updates, 17.04, 17.10

I started the update process from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10. During the process my system froze. Now it does not boot anymore. What can I do? What information do you need from me to help me solve this issue?

GNU Grub is still displayed, I can choose between

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options

  - Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-42 Generic
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-42 (upstart)
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 4.10.0-42 (recovery mode)
  - the same 3 options for older versions (4.10.0-22, 4.10.0-21, 4.10.0-19)

Recovery mode with option failsafeX results in "no screens found"

I have /dev with 3,9G used, 0G free (could this be the problem?)

I have /dev/sda6 with 41G used, 4G free

Comment: Where doest the system stop, when you try to boot ? Do you get to GRUB or .. ?

Comment: please elaborate more on the situation. at what point does it fail? do you get grub? does recovery mode work? do you see any errors? does it freeze or do you get kernel panic?

Comment: Grub still works, recovery mode still works, it only freezes when using Option Ubuntu in Grub. I do not get kernel panic.